Prove that $ \mathit{f}$ is continuous at$ x_0= 0$ if and only if $ \mathit{f}(0) = 0$
let  $ f $  be a function defined on $]-1, 1[$ . suppose that :
$
\exists k > 0, \ \forall x \in \, ] -1, 1[, \ |f(x)| \leq k|x|.
$
Prove that $ f $ is continuous at
$x_0 = 0 $ if and only if $f(0) = 0$.
its seems so trivial (even without the k part ),  I don't know where to start .

Prove that both sides of your "iff" are true.

What do you mean by "even without the $k$ part"? + edit your post to show why it seems trivial to you.

I suspect you are being asked to show this (yes, essentially obvious) fact using the $\epsilon = \delta$ definition of limits.

The way you currently wrote your question, you already have $f(0) = 0$, as $0\leq |f(0)| \leq k|0| = 0$. Did you mean "$\exists k >0, \forall x\in ]-1,1[ \setminus {0}$,..."?

Do you know sandwich theorem ?

@rafilou2003 from where i got the question no .
